# Text input view not render properly

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, stylesheet

As a beginner on React Native, I decided to have a look at layouts. I have a component like this with a text input component and a text component.

```
class TextView extends Component{
render(){
return(
  <View style = {{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor: 'pink'}}>
  <TextInput style = {TextInputStyle.default}/>
  <Text> Hello again! </Text>
  </View>
)
}
}
```

After calling `TextView` component on root file index.ios.js the output seems like this. 
[image]

As you can see only text if following the stylesheet but not the text input. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

This is what TextInputStyle looks like

```
const TextInputStyle = StyleSheet.create({
default : {
  color : 'darkgrey',
  fontSize : 14,
  backgroundColor : 'red',
  height : 20,
  width : 100,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, you have not specified what's inside **TextInputStyle.default**, may be that is overriding the css style. Try to wrap TextInput in a view.

```
  <View style = {{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor: 'pink'}}>
        <View>
          <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, width:150}}/>
        </View>
        <Text> Hello again! </Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: That is the right answer. I needed to wrap the `TextInput` in `View` component.